# Function expression call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I came across this `(document.createElement)('a');`.

How is it different from `document.createElement('a');`

Comment: There's no difference. It's the same as `5+10` vs `(5)+10`. However `(0,document.createElement)(a)` would make a great difference.

Comment: This is a completely different question than the earlier version which was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It's absolutely not different, and therefore unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

No difference.

Please read [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for more.

Comment: That documentation you linked has nothing to do with whether there is a difference or not?